# In ElasticSearch, is it better to search a single string built from field information or multiple fields as they are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am currently looking at the suitability of ElasticSearch for improving search performance.

I am processing market research data, where I have > 300 000 variables/possible answers for questions.

#### Current Data Structure:

The user selects multiple categories / variables / possible answers from a tree, using drag and drop.
For example, the user can drag 'Alcohol' across, and it will drag across 'Alcohol' and all it's children, or, the user can simply drag across Heineken.

Something like this:

```
Food & Drink
-- Alcohol
---- Beer
------ Brand Usage - Last 30 days
-------- Heineken
-------- Guinness
-------- Kilkenny
-------- Amstel
```

Each leaf node in this data be seen as follows:

```
{
  'name' => 'brand_usage_l30d', 
  'label' => 'Brand Usage - Last 30 days', 
  'category' => ['Food & Drink', 'Alcohol', 'Beer'], 
  'value' => "Heineken"
}
```

Because the tree is very large, it would require about 60MB of text. Due to this, the nodes are loaded on demand from the server.

In order to achieve this, information for the nodes is stored in MySQL (relational) using a tree-relational storage method called modified pre-order tree traversal (MPTT).

See [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database, Part 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

[image: Modified pre-order tree traversal]

The MPTT database records for the above tree are shown below:

[image]

In my use case, tree's are not added to, and hence do not need to be re-built.

#### Problems:

The MPTT storage means that nodes are stored as separate database records.
If the user searches for 'Bee', I need to return the 'Beer' node **AND** all of it's parents **AND** all of it's children.

It is easy to get children and parents with a basic SQL query, however it would not be performant to do this for each and every node that matches the search terms.

#### What I aim to achieve:

My proposed solution at the moment is as follows:

Create an index in ElasticSearch where only the leaf nodes are stored, each leaf node will carry the information on all of its ancestors. Either by searching `name`, `label`, `category`, `value` or by creating a full text `search_text` field.

```
{
  'id' => 100,
  'name' => 'brand_usage_l30d', 
  'label' => 'Brand Usage - Last 30 days', 
  'category' => ['Food & Drink', 'Alcohol', 'Beer'], 
  'value' => "Heineken",
  'search_text' => 'brand_usage_l30d|Brand Usage - Last 30 days|Food & Drink|Alcohol|Beer|',
  'ancestor_ids' => [4,5,6,7]
}
```

(Unfortunately I cannot use MySQL full text search because of concerns with upgrading to MySQL 5.6, hence why ElasticSearch is under consideration)

Currently implemented search is currently doing something like this:
`search_term = 'Bee Heineken'`

`SELECT id, ancestor_ids FROM table_name WHERE search_text LIKE '%Bee%' AND search_text LIKE %Heineken%`

I plan to get back all the id's and ancestor ID's of nodes matching the search terms into a set, and then query those from the database (which is quick and efficient - 20ms)

I have given full context above, so that other suggestions may be made.

In essence, **what I want to find out is the following**:

1. Is it better to build up a search text field and search that, or is it better to search each field individually. For example searching the latter would mean searching each of `name`, `label`, `category` (which is an array) as opposed to searching one field.
2. How do I achieve both of the above so that I can execute both and see performance differences.
3. I understand ElasticSearch is not designed to dish out thousands of ID's that I can use, I am worried about the performance of having to execute multiple requests to get back further lists of ID's. Can I get around this and only execute one HTTP request?

**Edit:** I am new to ElasticSearch

Comment: If you do a search in the MPTT storage is possible to get all content hierarchy? I mean, all nodes? all 300k+ possible situations?

Comment: If the search results in more than n results, then I'll tell the user the search is too broad. At the moment I see N being 10000.